# Convert UnicodeScalar index to String.Index

Tags: swift, string, unicode

I am using a parser that returns positions as UnicodeScalar indexes. On my side, I am using regular Swift String and `String.Index`.

How Can I convert an UnicodeScalar index to a regular String.Index, taking into account grapheme clusters?

```
let flags = ""
```

For instance, will start to create issue because it has 2 unicode scalars from a single char.

Note: I am using Swift 4.2

Comment: Added Swift version and example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various String views share a common index. If you have a position given as an offset into the UnicodeScalar view then use `String.unicodeScalars.index()` to convert it to a `String.Index`. Example:

```
let s = ""
print(Array(s.unicodeScalars))
// ["\u{0001F1E6}", "\u{0001F1F9}", "\u{0001F1E7}", "\u{0001F1EA}"]

let ucOffset = 2
let sIndex = s.unicodeScalars.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: ucOffset)
print(s[sIndex...]) //
```

The reverse calculation is done with `distance(from:to:)`. Example:

```
let s = ""

if let sIndex = s.index(of:"") {
    let ucOffset = s.unicodeScalars.distance(from: s.startIndex, to: sIndex)
    print(ucOffset) // 2
}
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks! How would you do the opposite?